# Mobile Value Added Service, MVAS protocols

Tags: telecommunication

I study the construction of mobile networks and began to study MVAS. But could not find a specific iinformation what protocols are used in the VAS or MVAS.

I understood that main protocol using SMS - it SMPP.
 
It would be great if someone made ​​a list of the protocols used, or links where I could read more information about the protocols used.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a list; it is published by 3GPP in specification [TS 23.039.](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/23039.htm)

3GPP (earlier ETSI) specified the GSM, UMTS and LTE systems, with standard protocols for most of the interfaces.  They did not specify any standard protocol between Short Message Service Centres and external messaging servers though.

Instead, this was left open, and each SMSC developer specified their own protocol.  An early and successful SMSC developer was an Irish company called Aldiscon, which was later taken over by Logica.  They developed the Short Message Peer-to-Peer protocol (SMPP), and published it as an open standard, which is the reason why it's so widely used today.